# What does "если форма его принята" mean?

Tags: грамматика

In the following sentence:

> Государство это устойчиво только при одном условии: если форма его принята добровольно.

I don't understand the second sentence, especially how его works. Based on the Google translate:

> This state is stable only on one condition: if its form is accepted voluntarily.

If this translation is correct, его seems to modify форма, but it is put after it, not before. принята is likely принять, in a form of past passive and the subject is omitted, if I understand it correctly.

But then why does его put in such a way? Or is it possibly a typo?

Comment: In fact the Russian phrase does not really make sense. It is not clear what "форма государства" means.

Comment: @markvs — In fact, the Russian phrase does make sense and it is pretty clear what “форма государства” means. If it's not clear _for you_, here's a clue: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Форма_государства

Comment: It is not clear for me because it does not make sense. You won't be able to prove the opposite to me  because  I have been speaking Russian for more than 60 years.

Comment: @markvs — It's good you agree it's not clear _for you_. Speaking a language for a whole life doesn't automatically mean knowing all the specialized terminology. For example I have been speaking Russian for more than 40 years and still don't know what “кейнсианство” and “банковский мультипликатор” mean, that does not make any sense _for me_. Never mind, it's OK if you don't know something, the point is to realize you don't know everything.

Comment: @YellowSky: This phrase does not make sense. As for Wikipedia article you referred to, everybody. even the most illiterate person can write a Wikipedia article. That is especially true for Russian Wikipedia.

Comment: @markvs — You're right, despite the fact that the article refers to actual works on state theory, anyone can write an article on Wikipedia. Just the same way as anyone can edit entries on Google translate which, nevertheless, you have as an authority.

Comment: @markvs — You could have googled the sentence. It is from the Russian textbook [Русский класс, 2006](http://public.freetorrent.ir:9001/The%20Ultimate%20Russian%20Learning%20Pack%20(Supplement)/41%20Русский%20класс%20учебное%20пособие%20по%20русскому%20языку%20как%20иностранному.pdf), p. 66, the very bottom: “Семья — маленькое государство. Тут возможны разные формы отношений: демократия, анархия, абсолютизм и даже, к сожалению, деспотия. _Государство это устойчиво только при одном условии: если форма его принята добровольно._” As you can see, the Wiki article I quoted is absolutely right.

Comment: @YellowSky: Whatever  you say, but there is no  such thing as "Форма государства". There is "форма правления". And this is what the authors of the textbook would write, if they had any decency.

Comment: markvs, "there is no such thing as "Форма государства". There is "форма правления"." - there no difference really. Only your stereotypes and stamps :> also besides the "форма правления" there is an "общественный строй", but all this doesn't change the matter - it's clear that the state (whatever it is and what an abstraction it is) - it has and can have a form of organization. Everything that exists has a form. :>

Comment: I'm a Russian native speaker and don't quite understand what does it mean lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know, you should not generally rely on word order in Russian. Look:

> При одном только условии устойчиво это государство: форма если добровольно принята его.

This is an absolutely correct sentence with the same meaning, just with a slightly different emphasis. Of course, some ways to say things are more common than others, some are plainly incorrect and some are more ambiguous than others, but flexibility is great.

The important fact is not the word order but that "его" has a Genitive relationship to "форма". Grammatically, the meaning would be absolutely identical if the sentence were

> ...если его форма принята добровольно.

Indeed, *this* form (pardon the pun) is "normal", or "neutral" in Russian, but the reverse order (this is called [инверсия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)) is also common. By the way, there is another example of it in your sentence: "государство это", and you didn't stumble over it.

---

There is a finer issue with this sentence related to the word order: does "только" relate to "условие" or "устойчиво"? Unlike "его", its grammatical form doesn't hint us. Yet logically, the meaning is drastically different: is there "only one condition" of stability, or is stability *only ensured* on this condition?

Obviously, the first interpretation is false and they *meant* the second one. (Although, who knows...) The way you translated it seems to retain this ambiguity. Yet, I'm not sure it's right, because in English with its stricter word order you can easily avoid such ambiguity:

> The state is stable on only one condition...

vs.

> The state is only stable on one condition...

If the first one were correct, they would have said "при только одном условии". Here, we infer the relationship from essentially the word order, even in Russian.

But if they said "...только устойчиво при одном условии...", like in the second English option, it would mean a different thing: only stable but nothing else, say, stable but not prosperous. This is almost non-sensical, so they did what they did, hoping that we'll parse the meaning correctly.

(This is why mathematicians love the construct "if and only if").

There is one form that would unambiguously say what (I believe) they mean, but it's a bit more colloquial:

> Вот только, государство это устойчиво при одном условии...

Anyway, *I think* it would be better to translate it "only stable", simply because you *can* resolve/reduce the ambiguity effectively. Also remember that when you see [demonstratives](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) like "это" in Russian, you often have the option of using "the" instead of literally translating "this" or "that".

Comment: Well, I assumed that on *государство это*, это works as a paraphrase of the subject, not as a demonstrative pronoun. I knew in Russian word order is relatively lax, but didn't know that demonstrative and possessive pronouns can also be separatable from the noun. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: "форма если добровольно принята его." - is not Russian even a little bit!

Comment: @Gangnus, absolutely it is. It is not _common_, but grammatically correct. Could be used in verses, for example. _Зададимся нынче мы вопросом: выживать легко  // Государству в двадцать первом веке? Отчего // Много лет подряд, меняясь, столь устойчиво порой оно? // Так бывает форма если добровольно принята его._

Comment: @Zeus I descend from a family of Soviet writers and poets. I myself worked as a journalist. Russian journalist. And I worked not in one of the contemporary non-edited illiterate periodic editions, but under a real editor - old-timer. And I was often praised for ideal Russian text. And I can definitely say that what you are citing, is not a literate Russian text, but absolute rubbish. Russian also has its order of words. That awful pseudopoetry cannot serve as an excuse for breaking the language.

Comment: @Gangnus, oh gosh, phallometrics, I'm more Russian than you. _Знаешь ли ты, чья кровь во мне? Гедимина кровь во мне! // И потому кичливости твоей не потерплю я._ I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 3):

Modifiers coming after the word they modify are quite common in Russian:

- государство это 'this state'
- форма его 'its form'

The subject of the second clause is форма (...its form is accepted).